# Using huber scale and location estimator in statsmodel

Tags: python-3.x, statsmodels

I want to use huber simultaneous scale and mean estimator found here : http://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.robust.scale.Huber.html but here is the error :

```
In [1]: from statsmodels.robust.scale import huber

In [2]: huber([1,2,1000,3265,454])
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-80c7d73a4467> in <module>()
----> 1 huber([1,2,1000,3265,454])

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/statsmodels/robust/scale.py in __call__(self, a, mu, initscale, axis)
    132         scale = tools.unsqueeze(scale, axis, a.shape)
    133         mu = tools.unsqueeze(mu, axis, a.shape)
--> 134         return self._estimate_both(a, scale, mu, axis, est_mu, n)
    135 
    136     def _estimate_both(self, a, scale, mu, axis, est_mu, n):

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/statsmodels/robust/scale.py in _estimate_both(self, a, scale, mu, axis, est_mu, n)
    176             else:
    177                 return nmu.squeeze(), nscale.squeeze()
--> 178         raise ValueError('joint estimation of location and scale failed to converge in %d iterations' % self.maxiter)
    179 
    180 huber = Huber()

ValueError: joint estimation of location and scale failed to converge in 30 iterations
```

The weird thing is that it depends on the input:

```
In [3]: huber([1,2,1000,3265])
Out[3]: (array(1067.0), array(1744.3785635989168))
```

Is it a bug or did I do something wrong here ?

Thanks

EDIT : I knew about the tol and maxiter parameter, what you say works in that case but here is an example where it doesn't :

```
In [1]: a=[4.3498776644415429, 16.549773154535362, 4.6335866963356445, 8.2581784707468771, 1.3508951981036594, 1.2918098244960199, 5.734
   ...: 9939516388453, 0.41663442483143953, 4.5632532990486077, 8.1020487048604473, 1.3823829480004797, 1.7848176927929804, 4.3058348043
   ...: 423473, 0.9427710734983884, 0.95646846668018171, 0.75309469901235238, 8.4689505489677011, 0.77420558084543778, 0.765060223824508
   ...: 45, 1.5673666392992407, 1.4109878442590897, 0.45592078018861532, 4.71748181503082, 0.65942167325205436, 0.19099796838644958, 1.0
   ...: 979997466466069, 4.8145761128848106, 0.75417363824157768, 5.0723603274833362, 0.30627007428414721, 4.8178689054947981, 1.5383475
   ...: 959362511, 0.7971041296695851, 4.689826268915076, 8.6704498595703274, 0.56825576954483947, 8.0383098149129708, 0.394000842811084
   ...: 22, 0.89827542590321019, 8.5160701523615785, 9.0413284666560934, 1.3590549231652516, 8.355489609767794, 4.2413169378427682, 4.84
   ...: 97143419119348, 4.8566372637376292, 0.80979444214378904, 0.26613505510736446, 1.1525345100417608, 4.9784132426823824, 1.07663603
   ...: 91211101, 1.9604545887151259, 0.77151237419054963, 1.2302626325699455, 0.846912462599126, 0.85852710339862037, 0.380355420248302
   ...: 99, 4.7586522644359093, 0.46796412732813891, 0.52933680009769146, 5.2521765047159708, 0.71915381047435945, 1.3502865819436387, 0
   ...: .76647272458736559, 1.1206637428992841, 0.72560665950851866, 4.4248008256265781, 4.7984989298357457, 1.0696617588880453, 0.71104
   ...: 701759920497, 0.46986438176394463, 0.71008686283792688, 0.40698839770374351, 1.0015132141773508, 1.3825224746094535, 0.932562703
   ...: 04709066, 8.8896053101317687, 0.64148877800521564, 0.69250319745644506, 4.7187793763802919, 5.0620089438920939, 5.17105647739872
   ...: 33, 9.5341720525579809, 0.43052713463119635, 0.79288845392647533, 0.51059695992994469, 0.48295891743804287, 0.93370512281086504,
   ...:  1.7493284310512855, 0.62744557356984221, 5.0965146009791704, 0.12615625248684664, 1.1064189602023351, 0.33183381198282491, 4.90
   ...: 32450273833179, 0.90296573725985785, 1.2885647882049298, 0.84669066664867576, 1.1481783837280477, 0.94784483590946278, 9.8019240
   ...: 792478755, 0.91501030105202807, 0.57121190468293803, 5.5511993201050887, 0.66054793663263078, 9.6626055869916065, 5.262806161853
   ...: 6908, 9.5905100705465696, 0.70369230764306401, 8.9747551552440186, 1.572014845182425, 1.9571634928868149, 0.62030418652298325, 0
   ...: .3395356767840213, 0.48287760518144929, 4.7937042347984198, 0.74251393675618682, 0.87369567300592954, 4.5381205696031586, 5.2673
   ...: 192797619084]

In [2]: from statsmodels.robust.scale import huber, Huber

In [3]: Huber(maxiter=10000,tol=1e-1)(a)
/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/statsmodels/robust/scale.py:168: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in sqrt
  / (n * self.gamma - (a.shape[axis] - card) * self.c**2))
/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/statsmodels/robust/scale.py:164: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in less_equal
  subset = np.less_equal(np.fabs((a - mu)/scale), self.c)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-4b9929ff84bb> in <module>()
----> 1 Huber(maxiter=10000,tol=1e-1)(a)

/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/statsmodels/robust/scale.py in __call__(self, a, mu, initscale, axis)
    132         scale = tools.unsqueeze(scale, axis, a.shape)
    133         mu = tools.unsqueeze(mu, axis, a.shape)
--> 134         return self._estimate_both(a, scale, mu, axis, est_mu, n)
    135 
    136     def _estimate_both(self, a, scale, mu, axis, est_mu, n):

/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/statsmodels/robust/scale.py in _estimate_both(self, a, scale, mu, axis, est_mu, n)
    176             else:
    177                 return nmu.squeeze(), nscale.squeeze()
--> 178         raise ValueError('joint estimation of location and scale failed to converge in %d iterations' % self.maxiter)
    179 
    180 huber = Huber()

ValueError: joint estimation of location and scale failed to converge in 10000 iterations
```

Sorry, this was my original error but because the "a" is long, I tried to recreate the error with a smaller array. In this case, I don't think maxiter and tol are to blame.

Comment: Try `Huber(maxiter=100)(yy2, initscale=np.array(44))` https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/issues/550

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of iterations allowed, maxiter, can be changed when using the Huber class.

e.g. this works

```
>>> from statsmodels.robust.scale import huber, Huber
>>> Huber(maxiter=200)([1,2,1000,3265,454])
(array(925.6483958529737), array(1497.0624070525248))
```

It is also possible to change the threshold parameter for the norm function when using the class. In very small samples like this the estimate might be very sensitive to the threshold parameter.

As alternative we can use the RLM model and regress on a constant, both thresholds and the algorithm are different but it should produce similar robust results. In the new example the estimate for the scale in between standard deviation and robust MAD, while the mean estimate is larger than the median and the mean.

```
>>> res = RLM(a, np.ones(len(a)), M=norms.HuberT(t=1.5)).fit(scale_est=scale.HuberScale(d=1.5))
>>> res.params, res.scale
(array([ 2.47711987]), 2.5218278029435406)

>>> np.median(a), scale.mad(a)
(1.1503564468849041, 0.98954533464908301)

>>> np.mean(a), np.std(a)
(2.8650886010542269, 3.0657561979615977)
```

The resulting weights show that some of the high values are downweighted

```
>>> widx = np.argsort(res.weights)
>>> np.asarray(a)[widx[:10]]
array([ 16.54977315,   9.80192408,   9.66260559,   9.59051007,
         9.53417205,   9.04132847,   8.97475516,   8.88960531,
         8.67044986,   8.51607015])
```

I am not familiar with the details of the implementation of the Huber joint mean-scale estimator.
One possible reason for the convergence failure is that the distribution of the values is bunched in 3 groups with one extra outlier at 16, visible when plotting the histogram. This could result in a convergence cycle with the iterative solver where the third group is either included or excluded. But that is just a guess.

Comment: In fact, this example was not my first error, I editted my first post to show the original error that I mistakenly tried to recreate with a smaller array for lisibility. So this does not answer my problem.

Comment: @tmathieu I don't have enough experience with this to provide a reliable answer, but I added an RLM version as alternative. Essentially, the three part distribution of `a` is not close to the normal reference case, and you need to decide whether the 15 observations in the last group should be treated as outliers or not.